# Problems with foo2zjs-z1 (HP Laserjet 1020)

Tags: drivers, printer

I can't find a way to operate an HP LaserJet 1020 printer (Debian Buster). HPLIP, of the repositories, does not work.
After cleaning the installation of HPLIP and correctly compiling foo2zjs-z1, adding the printer by CUPS, does not print (although it detects it).
Is there any way to operate the driver (or activate it)? Can I provide any log that serves to track the problem?
Sorry for My English